# array wrapped in parentheses in PHP (array)

Tags: php, arrays, parentheses

This is quite a simple question, but I am finding it hard to find an answer.

I have a script that has the following:

```
(array) $item->classes
```

I have seen `array()` but never `(array)`. What does it do?

Answer (score 9):

This is called typecasting. You can read more about on the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). `(array)` is used to convert `scalar` or `object` to `array` see [Converting to array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.casting)

Answer (score 2):

(array) will cast an object as an array

Assuming `$item->classes->attribute_a = 1` and `$item->classes->attribute_b = 2`,

```
$object_to_array = (array)$item->classes;
```

creates an associated array equivalent to  `array('attribute_a' => 1, 'attribute_b' => 2)`.

Typecasting is not just for arrays, it works between many different types.  For example an integer could be cast as a string;

```
$i = 123;
$string_i = (string)$i;
```

Much more on typecasting [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)